# Is it possible to create custom clients with Google API client libraries for Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client

I was wondering if there were chances to use something like the Google API Java Client to make a custom client for an application instead of starting from scratch.

I'm going to use Google App Engine to run it so it popped on my head if there were advantages in using something "touched" by Google Hands.

Have you ever tried something like this?

Comment: Could you give more details about *exactly* what you mean by "make a custom client"? What do you mean by "I'm going to use Google App Engine to run it" - run what, exactly? If you can make your question clearer, it'll be a lot easier to help you.

Comment: "google api java client" is a lib, a standard jar, you can build anything you want on top of this

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

YES!

As @igor-artamonov says you can build your custom REST Java client on top of Google API client libraries for Java.

You can find explanations and a full sample for [HubSpot API](http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/overview) here:

http://in.shangrila.farm/java-client-for-hubspot-api-built-on-top-of-google-api-client-for-java

**How to**

First of all I assume you use Maven, in this case you need to declare this dep

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
  <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
  <version>1.20.0</version>
</dependency>
```

then you will create the REST client class

```
public class YourOwnClient extends AbstractGoogleJsonClient {

  public static final String DEFAULT_ROOT_URL = "https://your.api.com";
  public static final String DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH = "";
  public static final String DEFAULT_BASE_URL = DEFAULT_ROOT_URL + DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH;

  [... required methods and constructor for AbstractGoogleJsonClient ...]

  public class YourOwnEndpoint {
        public Get get() throws java.io.IOException {
            Get result = new Get();
            initialize(result);
            return result;
        }

        public class Get extends YourOwnClientRequest<your.own.api.model.Pojo> {

            private static final String REST_PATH = "your/own/api/endpoint";

            protected Get() {
                super(YourOwnClient.this, "GET", REST_PATH, null, your.own.api.model.Pojo.class);
          }
        }
    }

  public static final class Builder
            extends com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClient.Builder {
        public Builder(com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport,
                com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory jsonFactory,
                com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer) {
            super(transport, jsonFactory, DEFAULT_ROOT_URL, DEFAULT_SERVICE_PATH, httpRequestInitializer, false);
        }

        @Override
        public YourOwnClient build() {
            return new YourOwnClient(this);
        }
    }
}
```

at this point you can use this like other Google API client

```
HttpTransport transport = new ApacheHttpTransport();
JsonFactory jsonFactory = new GsonFactory();
HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer = new BasicAuthentication("usr", "pwd");

YourOwnClient client = new YourOwnClient.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, httpRequestInitializer).build();

your.own.api.model.Pojo pojo = client.YourOwnEndpoint().get().execute();
```

That's it!

Comment: Is it even a good idea to write a custom client against a server ? The reason I am asking is when server code changes, you need to keep track of it very closely. On the same fact, if service consumer bump to new client SDK, then its highly confident that it works against new server. (Assuming server code can be incompatible over course of time...)

Comment: @BalajiBoggaramRamanarayan you know you are right, if there is an official Java client I will use it, but actually there isn't :D